# ownership of directory by apache

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have read a similar questions ans answers such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520634/giving-ownership-of-the-directory-to-the-apache-user). But I am still faced with one issue I haven't found a perfect solution for.

My situation is as follows: I have a symfony4 project located in `var/www/project`. Within this directory there are directories such as `scr`, `config`, `public` which are all owned by `user:user` (which has root access). Just one directory in this project, `var` (in which the cache and log are stored), is owned by `www-data:www-data`, so that apache can read and write to this directory.

Whenever I need to clear the cache I must run `php bin/console cache:clear`. I cannot do this as `user`, because of the permissions that are set. If I change the ownership with `sudo chown user:user var`, I can then do run the command. But apache won't be able to read the files any more. I could then change the ownership again with `sudo chown www-data:www-data var` and everything works again, but my guess is there must be an easier solution.

Addionional information: whenever the `php bin/console cache:clear` is executed, all files in the `var` directory are set with permissions 664.

I thought about changing the default user of Apache to `user`, but this user has root access, so this is a bad idea I think. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `user` account is not added to the `www-data` group.
Verify that the `user` account is in the `www-data` group by running the following command:

```
groups USER
```

(where USER is the username of the account) and checking if `www-data` is in the list of groups returned.

If not, add the `user` to the `www-data` group by:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data  USER
```

and verify again.

Reference: [Add a User to Group www-data](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group-www-data/)

Comment: I did this, but the problem still remains. There is a directory `var/cache/prod` with permission 755 so the user cannot write to it. I can change the permissions, but every time I would clear the cache these permissions are reset.

Comment: Another option to try: [Setting www-data and me as the owner](https://askubuntu.com/a/840138/902634).